# Conditional string splitting in Python using regex or loops

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, python-re

I have a string `c` that has a respective repetitive pattern of:

- integer from `0` to `10`,
- character `S`, `D`, or `T`,
- special character `*` or `#` (optional)

For instance, `c` could look like `1D2S#10S`, or `1D#2S*3S`, or so on.

I have a further calculation to make with `c`, but in order to do so I thought splitting `c` into substrings that include integer, character, and a possible special character would be helpful. Hence, for example, `1D2S#10S` would be split into `1D`, `2S#`, `10S`. `1D#2S*3S` would be split into `1D#`, `2S*`, `3S`.

I am aware that such string split can be concisely done with `re.split()`, but since this is quite conditional, I wasn't able to find an optimal way to split this. Instead, I tried using a `for` loop:

```
clist = []
n = 0
for i in range(len(c)):
  if type(c[i]) != 'int':
    if type(c[i+1]) == 'int':
      clist.append(c[n:i+1])
      n = i
    else:
      clist.append(c[n:i+2])
      n = i
```

This raises an indexing issue, but even despite that I can tell it isn't optimal. Is there a way to use `re` to split it accordingly?

Comment: Maybe better to use `re.findall` rather than `re.split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall()`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d*[SDT][\*#]?', '1D2S#10S')
['1D', '2S#', '10S']
>>> re.findall(r'\d*[SDT][\*#]?', '1D#2S*3S')
['1D#', '2S*', '3S']
```